# Регулярные выражения. c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Код:

```
string text = "aa hi hie";
Regex regex = new Regex("(hi)");
Match match = regex.Match(text, startIndex);
```

Проблема.
При Match'e я хочу убедиться, что моя искомая подстрока начинается именно с указанного startIndex (например 3 в нашем примере) и никак иначе. Т.е. я хочу добиться такого же результата, когда мы используем "^" в шаблоне.
Пока в голову приходило только делать Substring строки с указанного startIndex, а потом использовать шаблон:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^(hi)");
```

Но такое решение меня не очень устраивает. Хотелось бы узнать альтернативные решения.

Comment: `.{3}hi` - сперва три любых символа, потом шаблон. Не?

Comment: спасибо @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> искомая подстрока начинается именно с указанного startIndex

```
int startIndex = 3;
string text = "aa hi hie";

string pattern = $"^.{{{startIndex}}}(hi)";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = regex.Match(text);
```

Шаблон для поиска будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
^.{3}(hi)
```

Совпадения строго с начала строки, потом три любых символа, потом желаемое совпадение.

Comment: да, это работает. спасибо.
но такой вопрос. допустим, что у меня очень приочень большая строка. и допустим, что моя искомая подстрока находится в самом конце. 
если я буду использовать такой способ, то как будет вести себя Match? он будет с самого начала считать кол-во любых символов, а потом будет сопоставлять сам шаблон? если так, то не слишком ли это затратно? или же Match сразу проигнорирует ^.{{{startIndex}}}, прыгнет на startIndex и начнет сопоставлять шаблон. если так, то все хорошо. надеюсь, что я понятно написал.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (text.IndexOf("hi") == 3) { ... }
```

Comment: этот способ подошел, если бы мне действительно нужно было искать подстроку, как в примере. но в моей программе шаблон намного сложнее.